# ImportError: No module named pylab

Tags: python-3.x

I have read the similar questions already posted and the answers were over my head. I am very new to Python. I have Python 3.3.3 and keep getting the error message
"ImportError: No module named pylab" when I try import:pylab
How can I get what I need to use "pylab"? Any advice would be great. I'm just trying to make basic points on a graph.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `pip3 install -U matplotlib`. this will install the package for python 3.x.x

Comment: this worked for me, same problem, but I needed it strictly for python3

Answer (score 2):

You can import Pylab with the following:

```
from pylab import *
```

So, if you tip "import:pylab", then you are doing wrong...

To be able to import pylab, it must be already installed on your computer. 
If you are using Ubuntu, you can install it from your terminal with:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy python-matplotlib
```

Edit: Actually installing matplotlib is enough, it contains pylab. But you may soon need the other packages too...

Answer (score -1):

I have the same question.I can't ***import pylab***

so I try this

```
 $ pip3 install matplotlib
```

but it doesn't work for me.

Then I try this

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib
```

but it doesn't work neither.

Finally, I try

```
$ pip3 install -U matplotlib
```

**AND IT WORKS !!! :)**